# Understanding how UIPickerView works

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

fairly new, and I would need a hand understanding UIPickerViews.

I have created a UIPickerView programmatically for my project:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 375, 200)];
    myPickerView.delegate = self;
    myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myPickerView];   
}
```

And then added a method for the number of rows:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSUInteger numRows = 5;

    return numRows;
}
```

Which returns as expected five question marks. I could then go on to create an array to fill those rows etc... but instead I next add another UIPickerView like so:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 375, 200)];
    myPickerView.delegate = self;
    myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myPickerView];

    UIPickerView *my2PickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 375, 200)];
    my2PickerView.delegate = self;
    my2PickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:my2PickerView];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSUInteger numRows = 5;

    return numRows;
}
```

Now I have two pickerview controllers and they BOTH have five rows. My question is how do chose to which pickerview the method applies and also could anyone explain why does the method apply to all pickerviews in the project? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one delegate method for two PickerViews ; that's something I don't like with iOS but you don't really have a choice here.

You have to `if-statement` yourself out of this.

The `pickerView` parameter in the delegate method is the pickerview that is being assigned the number of rows.

Note that this is valid for any of the usual delegate methods for iOS, wether it's the numberOfRows of your pickerview, or your tableview, or your collectionView, or any delegate method that has the view in parameter.

The easy understandable way is to have your pickerview as fields of your class (or properties), and simply compare the parameter with it.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIPickerView *_mySexyPickerView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIPickerView *_myOtherPickerView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _mySexyPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 375, 200)];
    _mySexyPickerView.delegate = self;
    _mySexyPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:_mySexyPickerView];

    _myOtherPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 375, 200)];
    _myOtherPickerView.delegate = self;
    _myOtherPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:_myOtherPickerView];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (pickerView == _mySexyPickerView){
         return 2;
    }

    if (pickerView == _myOtherPickerView){
         return 19;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks great answer. I'm finding it challenging to understand delegation. Just out of interest, is there anything else that I could have written instead of "self" on this line: myPickerView.delegate = self;?

Comment: Anything could be your pickerviews delegate, but its common practice to give that role to the controller where the pickerview is (and therefore, self).

Comment: you can make a view controller a delegate of something only if it conforms to the protocol required.. for instance, here, self conforms to UIPickerViewDelegate and only because of that can you assign self as delegate of your 'myPickerView' property.

Comment: Ok I think I get it, I could create a class and make that the delegate. And that means that all the methods that control the number of rows, components, titles etc... would have to be implemented on that class. Would something like that make sense myPickerView.delegate = MyNewClass;? many tx

Comment: It would be okay yes. In that case you would have two separate classes (or instances of one class) to be delegates, which might be clearer than the ugly if statements

Comment: Ok thanks. One more thing, I am trying to do this: myPickerView.delegate = MyNewClass; but it's not working. I've never done something like this before so it may be something ridiculously simple I am forgetting. It works with myPickerView.delegate = self; but if i try to put the name of my class it comes back with "unexpected interface name ... expected expression. tx

Comment: It has to be an instance of the class, and the class needs to respond to the PickerViewDelegate protocol (the <blablablaprotocol> thing)